# How can I create a command by using Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I'm currrently learning on how to use WPF. And my objective was to create a command that will create grid layout. for example if I click the button1, it will create a `Grid` layout like this.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="235*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="113*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Author" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
```

I'm using WPF and c#.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to generate a Grid in the code-behind. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't try any code sir. I just want to know how to create a command for that problem.

Comment: Is the objective to generate these grids dynamically or just load a grid after pressing a button?

Comment: I want to load a grid after pressing button. Its just like appearing a text in desired location.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a User Control and a Content Presenter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx

Just create a user control in WPF and put your grid inside it. Then instatiate it like a class from the Main Window and set the Content Presenter's source to the User Control.

So:

```
UserControl UserControl1 = new UserControl();
ContentPresenter1.Content = UserControl1;
```

That's just the method I favor as you can have any number of controls in a user control which makes it easy to expand upon and add to your grid later.